# how i trigger javascript function in jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one javascript function. Which i want to call on hover of li

```
    var Divhtml='<div>hover</div>';
    $('li a').hover(function(){
             $(this).html(Divhtml);
             //here i want to fire hovercall(); which will work on "Divhtml" i.e. innerHtml,this contains visual effects,depending on Class
     });

     function hovercall()
     {
     }
```

please guide

Comment: `$(this).html(Divhtml).hover(hovercall);` perhaps? Though the question is unclear.

Comment: How does `hovercall` call work? What is it doing?

Comment: You question is very unclear. Please give more details as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: Um... I just re-read my comment above and saw my own grammatical errors. I am past the comment edit time window. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Divhtml='<div>hover</div>';
$('li a').hover(function(){
         $(this).html(Divhtml);
         hovercall();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(Divhtml).trigger("hover");
```

Use the jquery trigger event: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Answer (score 0):

Just call it within your function:

```
$('li a').hover(function(){
         $(this).html(Divhtml);
         hovercall(); 
 });
```